# How do you export Attached Documents from Database taken from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, sql-scripts

I'm currently trying to export attached files from a sql Database taken from a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 application. The attached files data are stored as BLOBs in a VARCHAR(MAX) datatype. Pictures of the database information attached below:

[Database Table Contents Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKyKr.png)

[Database Datatypes Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T76th.png)

So far, none of the sql scripts I've found have worked to extract the files and turn them into regular files. Usually, the scripts will throw the error "String or binary data would be truncated".

My goal is to have the BLOBs taken from the database to just be converted into files.

Is there a way inside of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 to just export the attached files as regular files? Or would it be easier to create a SQL Script to extract them and translate them into regular files?

Comment: Aren't BLOB files stored in Binary? You will likely have to convert them as its read otherwise it will just output the binary as it is which is probably your problem.  As to how to make M-D do it I have no idea, I personally handle it with my front end.

Comment: @easleyfixed the files are stored as a varchar. Before a file is created, does the data have to be in binary format?

Comment: BLOBs do not have to follow a given format.  They are a series of bytes, with each byte made up of 8 bits (a 1 or a 0, hence the “binary” descriptor) .  I'm not sure how your front end puts them back together, but I suspect it would be expecting binary data.

Comment: So maybe they do something different, THAT or when you import it as varchar it converts it, but if your stream is coming in non-binary for the insert. then perhaps either that is incorrect OR they do use that, but in either case, it has to be put back together.  Other than file rights issues, this is why I prefer file objects with logs pointing to their location  over storing files into dbs directly personally.  Not to mention God forbid your db gets corrupted O.O

Comment: that is base64, not binary